# unable to access certain php pages on localhost

Tags: php, mysql

I have a login page,login_form, menu page, and download page , this has been running successfully on a server earlier but i want all this to run on my local host, hence, I copied it all and put it in /var/www/html folder and was able to run the login page but the rest like menu.php and all dont come up.
IT has also a sql database which i just added into my system using, mysql -u root -p exaample < cs303.sql
and it is able to process normal select statements as well
Anybody here happens to know what is happening?

```
<?php

ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);

define ('HOSTNAME', 'localhost');           
define ('USERNAME', 'root');
define ('PASSWORD', 'merlin');
define ('DATABASE_NAME', 'wicap');


$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'merlin') or die ('Cannot connect to MySQL.'); // connecting to database
```

//echo"l;    km;l";
            mysql_select_db('wicap.sql');

```
        $v1=$_REQUEST["username"];
        $v2=$_REQUEST["password"];
//echo "sdfdf";
//$v1="ritish";
//$v2="ritish_r";
//echo($user);
//echo($pass);
        $q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login where pass='".$v2."' and user='".$v1."'");
        while($r=mysql_fetch_array($q))
        {

                echo($r[0].$r[1]+"/n");
                echo "mohit";

        }
 mysql_close();
```

?>

Comment: what error is coming on opening other pages?

Comment: it simply redirects the page or is it blank white.like if i type ...url/menu.php... it automatically opens  index.php.. and then its white blank page.

Comment: Are you able to connect to mysql?

Comment: You need to enable error_reporting in php. refer http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php so that you can see the error.

Comment: Can you also check what were the apache directives set for your project on the original server...were there any redirect rules that you have missed to add on your local setup. Also, IMO, on local setup, it is always good practice to enable the error_reporting directive of PHP so that you come at least come closer to finding the actual issue.

Comment: where do u suggest i put error_reporting(-1); this line, i mean which file of php.? INDEX, MENU,etc? –

Comment: <?php
$message="";
$flag=0;
if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
$uname = $_POST['t1'] ;
$pass = $_POST['t2'] ;
$pass = SHA1($pass);
define ('HOSTNAME', 'localhost');   
define ('USERNAME', 'root');
define ('PASSWORD', 'mysql');
define ('DATABASE_NAME', 'wicap');
  

$db = mysql_connect(HOSTNAME, USERNAME, PASSWORD) or die ('Cannot connect to MySQL.'); // connecting to database

mysql_select_db(DATABASE_NAME);   // select database

$query = "SELECT * FROM user_table where password = '$pass' and user_name = '$uname' ";  // check for entered username and password

Comment: @MerlinSundar: you will need two things: ini_set("error_reporting",1) to enable error reporting and ini_set("display_errors",1) to show the actual errors..put these two lines at the start of the script.

Comment: @MerlinSundar update your question with code rather posting in comments.

Comment: okabove <?php
I guess after that Vsingh right?

Comment: no after teh first"<?php" opening tag in the page..from there on your web server starts interpreting the php directives..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@MerlinSudar: for more clarity i am demonstrating the code here

```
<?php //first PHP opening tag

//put these lines 

ini_set("error_reporting",1)

ini_set('display_errors',1);

. //you code
. //you code
?>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

***Follow the below Step hope it will solve your problem...***

1) if you are using a xammp the put all your files in the htdocs folder, and if you are using the wammp the put all you file in www folder.

2)Check the linking of file, give the proper link connection.

Comment: i checked my index.php there a line states :
define ('DATABASE_NAME', 'wicap');
which is the name of the sql file.

Comment: I manually created a new database called "wicap" and added the previous database "cs303" into it. then checked , it seemed to work fine.
but if I have to check whether the file in the folder wicap.sql is the one being linked, HOw do i do that ?

Comment: where do u suggest i put error_reporting(-1); this line, i mean which file of php.?
INDEX, MENU,etc?

Comment: if you want to upload the previous database file, then go to database section and create the an empty database the  same name as the previous and then click on import tab and then select your db file have an extension of .sql, it will automatically create table in it.

Answer (score 0):

Enable error reporting

```
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
```

Add this code on top of your index file and check

Since mysql is deprecated, please dont use it anymore rather use the improved version
of mysql http://php.net/manual/de/book.mysqli.php

Comment: i have enabled this in index.php file and now it straightaway leads to login.php thats all.

Comment: hey it worked...
this is the error I recieved 
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /var/www/html/WicapDemo/login.php on line 13